# Minio Received non-HTTP message from new connection

Tags: minio

server error:
[image: server error]

Received non-http message from new connection

client error:
[image: client error]

code:

```
var endpoint  = "127.0.0.1:9000";
var accessKey = "MFQD47M******R5TZ1";
var secretKey = "WsuNQtYs********npA7iMRLjRmx";
var minio = new MinioClient(endpoint, accessKey, secretKey).WithSSL();
await minio.ListBucketsAsync();
```

Comment: please paste the actual text of your errors instead of images. (then they're searchable and re-usable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `.WithSSL()`. It seems like your server is expecting plain HTTP, but your client is expecting HTTPS. First try changing the client to plain HTTP. If that works, you'd probably want to properly enable HTTPS on your server so you have a secure connection.

https://docs.minio.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls